# Как сделать что бы значение присваивалось только одной ячейке?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
<?php 
require "config.php";
 ?>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

<?php 
$profile = mysqli_query($connection_mysqli , "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = " . (int) $_GET['id']);
$pro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($profile);
 ?>



<?php 
if(isset($_POST['do_add_friend'])){
$profile_add_friend = mysqli_query($connection_mysqli , "UPDATE `users` SET `friend` =  " .(int) $pro['id']);
}
 ?>


 <h3 id="h3">Profile of people <?php echo $pro['login']; ?></h3>

 <form action="/profile.php?id=<?php echo $pro['id']; ?>" class="form-input" method="POST">
 <button type="submit" name="do_add_friend"><p class="button-p">Add to friend</p></button>
 </form>
```

Вот собственно сам код , я незнаю что нужно дописать к строке(ниже) что бы
присваивалось только одной ячейке а не всем :

`<?php 
if(isset($_POST['do_add_friend'])){
$profile_add_friend = mysqli_query($connection_mysqli , "UPDATE`users`SET`friend`=  " .(int) $pro['id']);
}?>`

Comment: Нужно добавить условие `UPDATE users SET friend=  " .(int) $pro['id']) . "  WHERE id = " . $id`
Соответсвенно вам в форме нужно передать id нужного пользователя...для этого можно использовать `input hidden`

Comment: 1)Можно это сделать без input hidden а каким то другим методом?

Comment: можно еще один GET параметр добавить `<form action="/profile.php?id=<?php echo $pro['id'] ?>&user_id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>"` ну лучше и id и user_id передавать в `hidden input`

Comment: Еще вопрос , как сделать что id добавленных друзей накапливалось а не стояло одно id одного добавленного пользователя ?

Comment: Для этого нужно дополнительную таблицу делать как вариант, в которой будут связи друзей. Все в одну не выйдет...только, если делать сериалайз какой то...но не советую

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , в инете еще пороюсь для закрепления

Comment: @VladChyorny, оформите всё написанное выше как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для изменения одной записи нужно добавить условие выборки `where`

```
UPDATE users SET friend= " .(int) $pro['id']) . " WHERE id = " . $id
```

Соответсвенно вам в форме нужно передать id нужного пользователя...для этого можно использовать `input hidden`, аналогично советую использовать и для `$pro['id']` который вы передаете get параметром. Тогда ваша форма будет иметь примерно такой вид

```
<form action="/profile.php" class="form-input" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $pro['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo (int) $_GET['id']; ?>">
    <button type="submit" name="do_add_friend"><p class="button-p">Add to friend</p></button>
</form>
```

Для того чтоб можно было привязать несколько друзей как вариант нужно добавить дополнительную таблицу для сохранения связей. `user_friends` с польями `user_id, friend_id`. По `user_id` вы сможете заджйнить таблицы и получить список всех друзей пользователя. В данном случае связь односторонняя, т.е. это больше подходит не для друзей, а для подписок.

Comment: Получается в таблице user_friends , в колонку user_id нужно указать id пользователя на странице которого мы находимся?

Comment: верно, если подходит такой вариант